# Is it possible to send html with the mail intent?

Tags: android, html, email, content-type

is it possible to send html with the mail intent. I've seen some questions about this, but they are al answered with something like this:

```
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titleString);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

I'm trying to send some data in a table but the Html.fromHtml will remove my table layout..

Is there any other option to send a html content type email...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by the following work-around:

Create a html file and send it as a attachment..

Answer (score 1):

create email body with tags, that are supported by android.text.Html. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java

Comment: Than i will see the html source code in the mail client, same happends when i receive the email..