# Android sending email with css html embedded

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending a mail using intent from android application but my css is not loading. can someone help me load the css please. where am i wrong. Am stuck on this silly option for hours nows.

here part of my div.

`<div style="background:"+String.format(hex,colors.get(position).hex)"></div>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and couldnt fix it.
I don't think its possible to send css with the default email clients (correct me if i'm wrong).

My work around was sending the html as a attachment.

see:
[Is it possible to send html with the mail intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930812/is-it-possible-to-send-html-with-the-mail-intent)

**Edit:**
here is example how i did it:

- save the html as a file..
- add you attachments to a list of Uri objects
- see following code how to create a mail intent with the attachements..

  ```
  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
      emailIntent.setType("text/html");
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "title");

      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email body text");
      emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
  ```