# Android: prefilled email with html

Tags: android, html, email, utf-8

i have this code which prefill an email and throw an intent:

```
Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);   
email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
"iTempco"+getString(R.string.superficie_scambio));  
email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,{{here_the_html_code}});
email_intent.setType("text/html");  
startActivity(email_intent);
```

where you see {{here_the_html_code}} i have a string with html code (working perfectly).
the problem is that, when the activity is thrown, i see the html code (the source) in the text area of the client, not the "converted one"

how can i?

thanks.

Comment: You can't really tell how a external email program what to do, so I don't think you can expect most email program will actually take html as input through intent data...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but couldnt solve it.
Most of the default email client won't handle the html tags.
The best workaround i found is sending the html as a attachement.

check my question about this:
[Is it possible to send html with the mail intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930812/is-it-possible-to-send-html-with-the-mail-intent)

Comment: OK, if you find a solution without using a custom email client, please let me know.